# Returning an Interface from MVC Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have the following two classes

```
public interface INotification
{    
    int Id { get; set; }
    bool IsNotificationShown { get; set; }
    DateTime NotificationDate { get; set; }
}

public class Notification : INotification
{

    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool IsNotificationShown
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public DateTime NotificationDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

The WebAPI Controller has the following Action, I have hardcoded values for ease of read

```
    public List<INotification> Get()
    {
        INotification notif = new Notification { Id = 1, IsNotificationShown = false, NotificationDate = DateTime.Now, NotificationDescription = "Desc", NotificationFrom = "Abcd", NotificationTo = "Abcd", NotificationTypeId = 1 } ;
        return new List<INotification> { notif };
    }
```

When I run this on the browser I get the following error

**The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.**

As soon as I change the return type from INotification to Notification then it works fine.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: You can't serialize an interface - there is nothing to serialize.

Comment: So do I have to return a concrete type, cant the framework figure it out?  The whole purpose of using an interface is gone.

Comment: You'll have to cast the interface to the concrete type.  An interface doesn't contain data, so there is nothing to serialize over the wire.  An interface defines the properties/methods an implementing class has to implement, but the actual implementation (and data) is up to the concrete instance.

Answer (score 4):

Just add the attribute `KnowType` to your class. Like this:

```
[KnownType(typeof(Notification))]
public class Notification : INotification
{
...
```